# Singleton model for logged-in user

Tags: ember.js

I handle user login/registration without ember for now, but I'd like to handle user profile within ember (edit the profile). What would be the best course of action to have a singleton model that would handle current user? I defined a simple user as:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

I could populate it in `App.ready` but I am not quite sure how to do it with anything other than `App.User.find(id)` - and I don't know the id. My server can return just currently logged in user from this session, but how to use that in this case?
Or am I handling this in a wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) embeds the current user's information into the base HTML page and preloads it into a `User` model in the application route:

https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/routes/application_route.js

The `User` model then has enough information to access the users's profile/etc:

https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/models/user.js

The session specific items (such as logging out) access a separate `/session/` URL:

https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse.js#L169

If you are using sessions and you want to avoid embedding the current user information in your base HTML page (if you are serving content statically, etc) you could also manually access a session specific URL (such as `/session/`) that returns the currently logged in user's information according to the current session.

Answer (score 4):

I basically do what you are describing. I use the code below to make a call to the backend to get the currently logged in user and set it in the Ember application.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
});

App.deferReadiness();

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.user);

        App.store.load(App.User, resp.user._id, resp.user);
        App.store.load(App.Company, resp.company._id, resp.company);

        var user = App.User.find(resp.user._id);
        var company = App.Company.find(resp.company._id);

        App.CurrentUserController.reopen({
            content: user
        });

        App.CurrentCompanyController.reopen({
            content: company
        });

        App.advanceReadiness();
    },
    error: function (resp) {
        console.log('failed: ' + resp);
        App.advanceReadiness();
    }
});

App.initialize();
```

Comment: What would be the current method to do the same thing in the newer Ember? Because, it is saying that load() is not defined.?